# Volver a Pagina Anterior despues de actualizar

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy en un formulario de actualización y tiene en el link el id del registro a actualizar por ejemplo:
`view_fases.php?iddrs=2`

Lo mando a actualizar, y todo bien el problema viene cuando quiero que al acabar de hacer los cambios me regrese a la misma pagina con el id que se actualizo, Cómo podría colocarlo en el `header` dependiendo del id que se actualizo:

```
header("Location:view_fases.php?iddrs=");
```

Comment: el valor 2 que envias hace referencia al id2 o a numero 2
podrias agregar mas informacion de tu validacion y formulacion para comprenderlo mejor!

Comment: El numero 2  es referente al ID así que es el que cambiara constantemente por eso no se como ponerlo en el header para regresar

Comment: ya lo solucione con el 
javascript:history.back(-1);

XD

Comment: hola @laura si encontraste la solución a tu problema coloca una respuesta con la misma, eso ayuda a mejorar las estadísticas del sitio, y también otros usuarios pueden encontrarla útil.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo que mencionas en los [comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14208/volver-a-pagina-anterior-despues-de-actualizar#comment23524_14208) de `javascript:history.back(-1)`, pero eso puede presentar algunos problemas:

- Si el usuario tiene deshabilitado JavaScript, directamente no funcionará.
- El usuario puede ver una ventana en blanco antes de la redirección a la página anterior.
- JavaScript es un intermediario que está haciendo algo que podrías hacer directamente con PHP.
- Hacer un `history.back(-1)` puede dislocar la aplicación web (aunque si esto ocurre, tienes problemas más graves).

Es por ello que te recomendaría que la redirección la hicieses directamente con PHP, usando la función `header` que también mencionas en la pregunta. Por lo que comentas, lo único que te falta es pasar bien el parámetro con el ID. Pero eso es sencillo si la URL es `view_fases.php?iddrs=2` entonces tú código sería algo como esto:

```
<?php

    // lee el valor del parámetro iddrs
    $iddrs = $_GET["iddrs"];

    // haz las operaciones que tengas que hacer para la actualización
    // ...

    // redirecciona a la página anterior
    header("Location:view_fases.php?iddrs=" . $iddrs);
```

Un dato importante a tener en cuenta: la redirección con `header` dará un error si se ha escrito algún contenido antes (con `echo`, `print`, `var_dump`, etc.), porque no se puede cambiar la información de cabecera una vez que ha comenzado la salida de datos.

Answer (score 0):

debes llamar al `GET` que esta arriba en la barra del navegador `iddrs=(NUMERO)` con una función como esta:

```
header("Location:view_fases.php?$iddrs='.&_GET.'");
```